# SQL Server 2014 FULL OUTER JOIN issue

Tags: sql-server, outer-join

Have 2 tables

```
Preferences
```

where are listed all possible preferences with a query to select all allowed values:

```
+-----------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| Preferences               |       Query                                                     |
+-----------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| PickingList_Template  |   select v,n from Options where group='PickingList_Template'    |
| AWB_Template          |   select v,n from Options where group='AWB_Template'            |
| CheckList_Template    |   select v,n from Options where group='CheckList_Template'      |
| Manifest_Template     |   select v,n from Options where group='Manifest_Template'       |
| NoOfCopies            |   select v,n from Options where group='NoOfCopies'              |
    ...
```

and

```
UsersSelection
```

where each customers has a record with as many fields as the preferences:

```
+--------+--------------------------+-------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+----------------+
| UID    |  PickingList_Template    |   AWB_Template    |   CheckList_Template  |   Manifest_Template   |   NoOfCopies   |
+--------+--------------------------+-------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+----------------+
| User1  |      light               |       DHL         |       portrait        |        light          |       2        |
| User2  |      full                |       TNT         |       landscape       |       barcoded        |       0        |
...
```

Since I need to have the full list of preferences even if User has not selected any I used the Full Outer Join formula:

```
SELECT
    p.LookupQuery, 
    su.Name,
    su.Surname,
    su.Admin,
    us.* 

FROM 
    eBay.dbo.UsersSelection     us
FULL OUTER JOIN 
    dbo.Preferences             p   ON 1=1
FULL JOIN 
    dbo.Users                   u   ON u.UID=us.UID
FULL JOIN 
    dbo.SubUsers                su  ON su.UID=u.UID
WHERE 
    (su.SUID=@SUID COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS OR su.SUID IS NULL) 
AND 
    (su.PWD=@PWD COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS or su.PWD IS NULL)
ORDER 
    by p.SortOrder ASC
```

The Stored Procedure works.. but return the correct value only if UsersSelection is empty or if there is only the record that matches @SUID and @PWD exists:
if there is more than 1 record in UsersSelection it returns all records, while, clearly, I need only the values relative to selected user if any or empty values.

How can I achieve this?

sqlFiddle Schema

```
CREATE TABLE Preferencs (
  Preference nvarchar(30) NULL,
  Query nvarchar(300) NULL,
  SortOrder int NULL
)

CREATE TABLE UsersSelection(
  UID nvarchar(20),
  PickingListTemplate nvarchar(30) NULL,
  AWB_Template nvarchar(30) NULL,
  CheckList_Template nvarchar(30) NULL,
  Manifest_Template nvarchar(30) NULL,
  NoOfCopies int
)

CREATE TABLE SubbUsers(
  SUID nvarchar(30) NULL,
  PWD  nvarchar(30) NULL,
  Name nvarchar(60) NULL,
  Surname nvarchar(60) NULL
)

Insert into SubbUsers VALUES ('User1','pw1','John','Smith')
Insert into SubbUsers VALUES ('User2','pw2','Jack','Smith')
Insert into SubbUsers VALUES ('User3','pw3','Joe','Smith')

Insert into Preferencs VALUES ('PickingList_Template','select v,n from Options where group=''PickingList_Template''',1)
Insert into Preferencs VALUES ('AWB_Template','select v,n from Options where group=''AWB_Template''',3)
Insert into Preferencs VALUES ('CheckList_Template','select v,n from Options where group=''CheckList_Template''',5)
Insert into Preferencs VALUES ('Manifest_Template','select v,n from Options where group=''Manifest_Template''',8)
Insert into Preferencs VALUES ('NoOfCopies','select v,n from Options where group=''NoOfCopies''',6)

insert into UsersSelection VALUES ('User1','light','DHL','portrait','light',2)
insert into UsersSelection VALUES ('User2','full','TNT','landscape','barcoded',0)
insert into UsersSelection VALUES ('User3','light','FEDEX','portrait','barcoded',1)
```

Query:

```
Declare @SUID nvarchar(20)='User1', @PWD nvarchar(20)='pw1'

SELECT
    p.Query, 
    su.Name,
    su.Surname,
    us.* 

FROM 
    eBay.dbo.UsersSelection     us
FULL OUTER JOIN 
    dbo.Preferencs              p   ON 1=1
FULL JOIN 
    dbo.SubbUsers               su  ON su.SUID=us.UID
WHERE 
    (su.SUID=@SUID COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS OR su.SUID IS NULL) 
AND 
    (su.PWD=@PWD COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS or su.PWD IS NULL)
ORDER 
    by p.SortOrder ASC
```

Sorry but can't make sqlfiddle work.. when run SQL... return an error

here expected output:

```
1) if in UsersSelection there is a record with UID='User1' this result (and also other records related to other users)
+-----------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+----------+--------------------------+-------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+----------------+
| Preference            |       Query                                                     |   UID    |  PickingList_Template    |   AWB_Template    |   CheckList_Template  |   Manifest_Template   |   NoOfCopies   |
+-----------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+----------+--------------------------+-------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+----------------+
| PickingList_Template  |   select v,n from Options where group='PickingList_Template'    |  User1   |      light               |       DHL         |       portrait        |        light          |       2        |
| AWB_Template          |   select v,n from Options where group='AWB_Template'            |  User1   |      light               |       DHL         |       portrait        |        light          |       2        |
| CheckList_Template    |   select v,n from Options where group='CheckList_Template'      |  User1   |      light               |       DHL         |       portrait        |        light          |       2        |
| Manifest_Template     |   select v,n from Options where group='Manifest_Template'       |  User1   |      light               |       DHL         |       portrait        |        light          |       2        |
| NoOfCopies            |   select v,n from Options where group='NoOfCopies'              |  User1   |      light               |       DHL         |       portrait        |        light          |       2        |


2) if there is not a record related to user1 this result

+-----------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+----------+--------------------------+-------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+----------------+
| Preference            |       Query                                                     |   UID    |  PickingList_Template    |   AWB_Template    |   CheckList_Template  |   Manifest_Template   |   NoOfCopies   |
+-----------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+----------+--------------------------+-------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+----------------+
| PickingList_Template  |   select v,n from Options where group='PickingList_Template'    |  NULL    |      NULL                |       NULL        |         NULL          |        NULL           |     NULL       |
| AWB_Template          |   select v,n from Options where group='AWB_Template'            |  NULL    |      NULL                |       NULL        |         NULL          |        NULL           |     NULL       |
| CheckList_Template    |   select v,n from Options where group='CheckList_Template'      |  NULL    |      NULL                |       NULL        |         NULL          |        NULL           |     NULL       |
| Manifest_Template     |   select v,n from Options where group='Manifest_Template'       |  NULL    |      NULL                |       NULL        |         NULL          |        NULL           |     NULL       |
| NoOfCopies            |   select v,n from Options where group='NoOfCopies'              |  NULL    |      NULL                |       NULL        |         NULL          |        NULL           |     NULL       |
```

Comment: Can you post demo data to http://sqlfiddle.com so that we can write queries against that? I think what you're looking for is a [pivot](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/spike/2009/03/03/pivot-tables-in-sql-server-a-simple-sample/) query.

Comment: I've tried but cannot make it work.. 
just added everything to build sqlFiddle.. if you succeed..
tks!

Comment: Yeah, sqlfiddle seems to have a technical issue right now. Can you please also provide a mockup of the query result you want to get?

Comment: Sure, just added, thanks a lot!